# Calculating Norms for the Transpose

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces, operator-algebras

How does one show that the transpose mapping $T: \mathcal{M}_{n} \to \mathcal{M}_{n}$, given by $T(a)=a^{t}$, has norm $||T||=1$ but completely bounded norm $||T||_{CB}=n$?

**Notation.** $\mathcal{M}_{n}$ denotes the space of $n \times n$ matrices.

*Reference:* Example 1.1.6 from http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7188v3.pdf

There's a proof included in the reference. However, I am interested in alternate ways to calculate the norms above.

Comment: It would be nice to avoid external references and instead include the proof for which you want to have an alternative. Also, since there are *many* norms, it might be helpful to define which norms do you consider.